# What's the difference between ng-model and ng-bind

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-bind

I'm currently learning AngularJS and am having difficulty understanding the difference between `ng-bind` and `ng-model`.

Can anyone tell me how they differ and when one should be used over the other?

Answer (score 841, accepted):

**ng-bind** has one-way data binding ($scope --> view). It has a shortcut `{{ val }}`
which displays the scope value `$scope.val` inserted into html where `val` is a variable name.

**ng-model** is intended to be put inside of form elements and has two-way data binding ($scope --> view and view --> $scope) e.g. `<input ng-model="val"/>`.

Comment: Thanks tosh.  Would it be a fair assumption to say that ng-bind is only required where the value to display does not require user input.  And, ng-modal would be used for values (<input>) that do.  The angular documentation seems to suggest this but I'm after a better understanding.

Comment: @Marc Actually ng-bind binds the text content of the element, not its value. Because of this, it can't be used in <input> elements.

Comment: @Marc, in that case, just use: <input type="text" value="{{prop}}" />

Comment: @Marc: I find it strange, too. As angular strives to isolate us from HTML quirks, I'd expect it to [abstract from such details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607941).

Comment: A minor update on the topic. The ng-bind directive could be emulated with {{::val}} in order to achieve one-way data binding. That is very helpful when reducing the number of watchers.

Comment: @JakubBarczyk {{::va}} is one time binding and not one way.

Comment: @Wachburn It's one-way but more important it's one-time. It stops watching model changes after model takes any value. So it can't be used as one-way binding if we need regular one-way binding.

Comment: so what is the difference between ng-bind and {{}} ?

Comment: @ANinJa, please check differences here..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741586/difference-between-ng-bind-and-interpolation-in-angular

Answer (score 142):

*tosh*'s answer gets to the heart of the question nicely. Here's some additional information....

## Filters & Formatters

`ng-bind` and `ng-model` both have the concept of transforming data before outputting it for the user. To that end, `ng-bind` uses *filters*, while `ng-model` uses *formatters*.

### filter (ng-bind)

With `ng-bind`, you can use a *filter* to transform your data. For example,

`<div ng-bind="mystring | uppercase"></div>`,

or more simply:

`<div>{{mystring | uppercase}}</div>`

Note that [`uppercase` is a built-in angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/uppercase), although you can also [build your own filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09).

### formatter (ng-model)

To create an ng-model formatter, you create a directive that does `require: 'ngModel'`, which allows that directive to gain access to ngModel's `controller`. For example:

```
app.directive('myModelFormatter', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
     controller.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        return value.toUpperCase();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your partial:

```
<input ngModel="mystring" my-model-formatter />
```

This is essentially the `ng-model` equivalent of what the `uppercase` *filter* is doing in the `ng-bind` example above.

---

## Parsers

Now, what if you plan to allow the user to change the value of `mystring`? `ng-bind` only has one way binding, from **model**-->**view**. However, `ng-model` can bind from **view**-->**model** which means that you may allow the user to change the model's data, and using a *parser* you can format the user's data in a streamlined manner. Here's what that looks like:

```
app.directive('myModelFormatter', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
     controller.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        return value.toLowerCase();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

---

[**Play with a live plunker of the `ng-model` formatter/parser examples**](http://plnkr.co/edit/QFrHJMm9p14EgGpTDr13?p=preview)

---

## What Else?

`ng-model` also has built-in validation. Simply modify your `$parsers` or `$formatters` function to call [**ngModel**'s `controller.$setValidity(validationErrorKey, isValid)` function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

**[Angular 1.3 has a new $validators array](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)** which you can use for validation instead of `$parsers` or `$formatters`.

**[Angular 1.3 also has getter/setter support for ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)**

Comment: + 1. Thanks for the extra info. Its always good/great to have a quick answer (Tosh's) and then a detailed WHY & HOW answer like yours to learn/understand the more in reasoning/use cases.

Answer (score 30):

## ngModel


The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope.

This directive executes at priority level 1.

Example [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/JppOnZH0OYTACIZHLh64?p=preview)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
angular.module('inputExample', [])
   .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.val = '1';
}]);
```

**CSS**

```
.my-input {
    -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
    transition:all linear 0.5s;
    background: transparent;
}
.my-input.ng-invalid {
    color:white;
    background: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="inputDescription">
   Update input to see transitions when valid/invalid.
   Integer is a valid value.
</p>
<form name="testForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input ng-model="val" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" name="anim" class="my-input"
         aria-describedby="inputDescription" />
</form>
```

**ngModel is responsible for:**

- Binding the view into the model, which other directives such as
  input, textarea or select require.
- Providing validation behavior (i.e. required, number, email, url).
- Keeping the state of the control (valid/invalid, dirty/pristine,
  touched/untouched, validation errors).
- Setting related css classes on the element (ng-valid, ng-invalid,
  ng-dirty, ng-pristine, ng-touched, ng-untouched) including
  animations.
- Registering the control with its parent form.

## ngBind


The ngBind attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to update the text content when the value of that expression changes.

This directive executes at priority level 0.

Example [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/XpnZ6tlKydQ2IRktAJsS?p=preview)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
angular.module('bindExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Whirled';
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Enter name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></label><br>
  Hello <span ng-bind="name"></span>!
</div>
```

**ngBind is responsible for:**

- Replacing the text content of the specified HTML element with the
  value of a given expression.

Comment: Although I appreciate this thorough response, my previously selected answer will remain as it provided just enough information to **understand** the difference.

Answer (score 10):

If you are hesitating between using [**`ng-bind`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) or [**`ng-model`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel), try to answer these questions:

---

> Do you **only** need to **display** data?

- Yes: `ng-bind` *(one-way binding)*
- No: `ng-model` *(two-way binding)*

> Do you need to **bind text content** (and not value)?

- Yes: `ng-bind`
- No: `ng-model` *(you should not use ng-bind where value is required)*

> Is your tag a HTML **`<input>`**?

- Yes: `ng-model` *(you cannot use ng-bind with `<input>` tag)*
- No: `ng-bind`

Answer (score 6):

**ng-model**

ng-model  directive in AngularJS is one of the greatest strength to bind the variables used in application with input components. This works as two way data binding. If you want to understand better about the two way bindings, you have an input component and the value updated into that field must be reflected in other part of the application. The better solution is to bind a variable to that field and output that variable whereever you wish to display the updated value throughoput the application.

**ng-bind**

ng-bind works much different than ng-model. ng-bind is one way data binding used for displaying the value inside html component as inner HTML. This directive can not be used for binding with the variable but only with the HTML elements content. Infact this can be used along with ng-model to bind the component to HTML elements. This directive is very useful for updating the blocks like div, span, etc. with inner HTML content.

[This example](http://www.javabeat.net/angularjs-ng-model-ng-bind/) would help you to understand.

Answer (score 5):

```js
angular.module('testApp',[]).controller('testCTRL',function($scope)
                               
{
  
$scope.testingModel = "This is ModelData.If you change textbox data it will reflected here..because model is two way binding reflected in both.";
$scope.testingBind = "This is BindData.You can't change this beacause it is binded with html..In above textBox i tried to use bind, but it is not working because it is one way binding.";            
});
```

```css
div input{
width:600px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<head>Diff b/w model and bind</head>
<body data-ng-app="testApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="testCTRL">
        Model-Data : <input type="text" data-ng-model="testingModel">
        <p>{{testingModel}}</p>
          <input type="text" data-ng-bind="testingBind">
          <p ng-bind="testingBind"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

**ngModel** usually use for input tags for bind a variable that we can change variable from controller and html page but **ngBind** use for display a variable in html page and we can change variable just from controller and html just show variable.

Answer (score 1):

We can use ng-bind with `<p>` to display, we can use shortcut for `ng-bind {{model}}`, we cannot use ng-bind with html input controls, but we can use shortcut for `ng-bind {{model}}` with html input controls.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter Something"/>
<input type="text" value="{{name}}" placeholder="Enter Something"/>
  Hello {{name}}
<p ng-bind="name"</p>
```