# Reset a textarea after input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textarea

I am using AngularJS for a simple SPA.

This application includes a `<textarea>` which shows, by default a value from a binding:

```
<textarea>{{activeField.rawContent}}</textarea>
```

One should be able to edit content in this textarea, then save it to a database.

My problem is, as soon as an input was made, the textarea will save this input and afterwards no more show the content of the binding, even when `activeField.rawContent` is updated.

How could i prevent this behaviour?

Comment: try `<textarea ng-model="activeField.rawContent"></textarea>`

Comment: @KhanhTO
It seem's to work... would you mind to explain this to me? Thank you very, very much so far.

Comment: Your example is simply inserting a variable at the `textarea`, you have to BIND the data with `ng-model`. If this isn't there, how does it know to update when a change is made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{{}}` is actually `ng-Bind` behind the scenes which is one-way data binding.

`ng-model` is two-way data binding.

In your code, what you actually do is *inserting text content*, not bind the data. It's recommended in angular documentation to use ng-model in this case. Try changing it to:

```
<textarea ng-model="activeField.rawContent"></textarea>
```

For more information, check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419619/whats-the-difference-between-ng-model-and-ng-bind), [ng-model](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel), [ng-bind](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBind)

Answer (score 1):

When binding editable data to input/textarea fields you need to use the ng-model directive. This hooks into the elements change events and propagates the changes back to the model.

In this case you would implement this with:

```
<textarea ng-model="activeField.rawContent"></textarea>
```