# Shouldn't ng-bind work for input as well?

Tags: html, angularjs, readonly

I was a bit puzzled by my

```
<input ng-bind="x.a * x.b" tabindex="-1" readonly/>
```

expression not working. I can't use `ng-model` there (as the product is no L-value), so I blindly switched to `ng-bind`. I guess, it doesn't work because of the funny HTML inconsistency (using `value=xxx` instead of placing the value in the element text). So I switched to

```
<input value="{{x.a * x.b}}" tabindex="-1" readonly/>
```

which solved the problem, but shouldn't `input ng-bind` work anyway? AFAIK [jQuery `val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val) does. Am I doing something wrong?

Side questions:

- Is it a bad practice to use inputs which are always `readonly`?
- If so, what's the recommended way? `span` or `label` or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngBind` set's the element's **text** content:

```
element.text(value == undefined ? '' : value);   // from the source code of Angular
```

So, it does not work for setting the value of an input (nor shouldn't it).

I believe it is better to use `<span>` in place of readonly inputs.

Comment: I see... but given that `ngModel` work with both `input` and `textarea` (i.e., uses `value` or the child text as appropriate) I wonder why `ngBind` isn't equally smart.

Comment: First of all, `ngModel` does nothing - it is the `input` and `textarea` directives that do. And in both cases the change the element's value. Test with a textarea for yourself: it's the value that changes not textContent.

Comment: I didn't say `ngModel` does it, I said "it works with" (which in my BFU view is correct, but you're right). Concerning `textarea` I disagree: There's `<textarea ng-bind="item.volume" class="ng-binding">0.077</textarea>` in my rendered view and I can see no `value` attribute [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp). And I was wrong concerning `jQuery val()`.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying (it's probably me). There is of course no `value` attribute, but there is a `value` property (and don't use w3schools as a reference - every time you do a kitten dies :(). In any case, `ngModel` is used by the `textarea` directive to set the `value` property of the element (so `ngModel` is not smart - the `textarea` directive does it). `ngBind` on the other hand uses jQuery's `.text()` method which sets the content of the element: It just happens that `<textarea>` can have a TextNode content, whereas `<input>` cannot have content (only value).

Comment: OK, I'm convinced that your description is right. My point was simply that I don't care and don't want to care if an element uses its `value` or text or whatever (I consider the very existence of `value` superfluous, but I might be wrong again). I wrote a directive binding to either of them and it works fine. And I decided to do [something for the poor kittens](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/w3schools-hider/igiahejkpbnbnekdaefddmdceocmjpll).