# ng-bind works as a directive of textarea but not input tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs, and while i was exploring `ng-bind`, i noticed that it can be used as a directive of `textarea` ::

```
<input type="text" ng-model="review.start"/> 

<textarea ng-bind="review.start"> </textarea>
```

Thus the text i wrote in input tag was also reflected in the `textarea` field by data binding.

But `ng-bind` did not work with `input` tag.. I think `ng-bind` was not supposed to be used with user inputs. Angular docs are also not shedding much light on this.

So, was it made to work only with textarea in case of user inputs or something else?

Thanks,

Comment: Hmm. Looks like the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/textarea) is wrong. "The data-binding and validation properties of this element are exactly the same as those of the input element."

Comment: please check the answer here on the difference between ngBind and ngModel http://stackoverflow.com/q/12419619/3109205

Comment: @teleaziz yes, i went through that post earlier, and it nowhere says to use ng-bind in textarea or input fields. So, i am confused .

Comment: Technically `ngBind` works on input elements too in the sense that the element's textContent is updated. It's just that the text you see in the input is its value, not its textContent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is peace of code from `ngBind` directive from Angular.JS

```
scope.$watch(attr.ngBind, function ngBindWatchAction(value) {
    element.textContent = value === undefined ? '' : value;
});
```

As you can see, when it find change in attribute **ngBind**, it set `element.textContent` to changed value.

For `input` DOM `textContent` property does not set it's value. While with **textarea** DOM works with `textContent` property.

Comment: Angular source code is actually the best documentation :)

Answer (score 2):

`ngBind` can work with any element whose contents can be replaced with text.

According to the Angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind):

> The ngBind attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the
>   specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to
>   update the text content when the value of that expression changes.

That includes:

```
<div>Text</div>
<textarea>Text</textarea>
<span>Text</span>
<h1>Text</h1>
etc...
```

It will not work with:

```
<input />
<select></select> (requires <option> as children)
<ul></ul> (requires <li> as children)
etc...
```