# all the checkboxes are getting checked on clicking a single checkbox

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

i have a list of checkboxes in my angularjs code. when i click a checkbox, all the checkboxes get activated. How can i check only a single checkbox?

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<p>Type a letter in the input field:</p>
<form action="">
<p><input type="checkbox" ng-model="alpha" value="a">a</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" ng-model="alpha" value="b">b</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" ng-model="alpha" value="c">c</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" ng-model="alpha" value="d">d</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" ng-model="alpha" value="e">e</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" ng-model="alpha" value="f">f</p>
</form>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:alpha">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        'Jani',
        'Carl',
        'Margareth',
        'Hege',
        'Joe',
        'Gustav',
        'Birgit',
        'Mary',
        'Kai'
    ];
});
</script>

<p>The list will only consists of names matching the filter.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

the code is working fine when i use radio buttons.. 
 this is the problem i'm facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checkboxes need to have different values for `ng-model`. `ng-model` is what binds your view to your scope. So in your case, when you set one checkbox to `true`, all the others with the same `ng-model` value will be updated to `true`. This is the magic of Angular's two-way data binding.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419619/whats-the-difference-between-ng-model-and-ng-bind) for more info on `ng-model`.

Comment: if i give different values to ng-model, how vl <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:alpha"> this work??
i want to filter the list based on the values of checkboxes
basically the prog is all about filtering

Comment: Have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65Pyj/) and tell me if it helps you.

Comment: yup.. it helpedme.. thanxalot :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your logic. You said

```
<p>Type a letter in the input field:</p>
```

and

> basically the prog is all about filtering

But you're using checkboxes. Idealy, you should replace all your checkboxes with

```
<input type="text" ng-model="alpha"/>
```

Right ?

Comment: i'm srry.. initialli i had used a textbox, i forgot to edit tat wen i wanted to use checkbox