# call a value in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, binding

I want to call a particular value in my app through AngularJS

here is my controller(js file)

```
//infocomnamebyid
            $http.get('/csuv5.asmx/infocomname', {
                params: {
                    id: $scope.additionalinfoparam.Id
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                {
                    $scope.comnamebyinfo = response.data.info;
                    console.log(response.data.info);
                }
            });
        }
```

the value is printing in console like this

```
    [Object]
0
:
Object
comname
:
"QED Productions Pvt Ltd"
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array[0]
```

but now I want to print the same on my label

```
<label></label>
```

Comment: Did you try `<label>{{comnamebyinfo}}</label>`?

Comment: @Nishant123 yes i tried but not working

Comment: the data is coming in json format

Comment: try this, <label>{{comnamebyinfo[0}.comname}</label>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try JSON.parse()

```
 $scope.comnamebyinfo = JSON.parse(response.data.info);
```

and in HTML,

```
 <label ng-model="comnamebyinfo"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your label a model:

```
<label ng-model='aName'></label>
```

Then you can assign a value to it in your controller:

```
$scope.aName = response.data.info;
```

Comment: still no data is coming in my label

Comment: Can you provide all of your js and html

Answer (score 0):

There would be no reason to use two-way binding for a label. This means, instead of using the **ng-model**, you could:

1) String interpolation:

```
<label> {{ comnamebyinfo }}</label>
```

or 2) The **ng-bind** directive:

```
<label ng-bind="comnamebyinfo"></label>
```

More information about the differences between those options can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419619/whats-the-difference-between-ng-model-and-ng-bind).