# Angularjs Scope Variable does not Update View

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen this issue a lot on SO, but none of the solutions I have tried are working for me.  I tried using `$apply()` which gives me an error stating that the digest cycle is already running.  I tried using the Dot "." notation, but nothing changes.  I even tried using timeout and promises, but still it does not update in the view.

Here is the HTML:

```
<th colspan="4" ng-class="{'ssqtrue': deficiencies === false , 'ssqfalse': deficiencies === true}">
<span ng-model="definfo">{{definfo}}</span>
    </th>
```

Here is my Controller code:

```
    $scope.recalculateDashboard = function (goToDashboard) {
    contractorService
      .calculateScores()
      .success(function () {
          getscoringDetails();
          getDefInfo();
          if (goToDashboard) {
              $scope.tabs[0].active = true;
          }
      }).error(function (reason) {
          console && console.log(reason.statusText);
          genericErrorAlertHandler();


      });
};

function getDefInfo() {
    contractorService.getDeficiencyInfo()
      .success(function (data) {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.definfo = data;
            });
          if ($scope.definfo == 'No Deficiencies Found') {
              $scope.deficiencies = false;
          } else {
              $scope.deficiencies = true;
          }
      }).error(function (reason) {
          console && console.log(reason.statusText);
          genericErrorAlertHandler();


      });
}
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out what is going on here.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can not bind `ng-model` to `span`, and use `then` function instead of `success` because it deprecated.

Comment: Read the difference between [ng-model and ng-bind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12420157/5447994)

Comment: ng-bind was there first and wasn't working so I changed it to ng-model

Comment: Please post `getDeficiencyInfo` logic for full picture

Comment: getDeficiencyInfo is an $http call in my service.   this.getDeficiencyInfo = function () {
    return $http.get('/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/GetDeficiencyInfo');
  };

Comment: @RaniRadcliff are you able to reproduce it outside of your project? Possibly create a fiddle and show us the full picture please, since your code looks good except the points mentioned by Maxim.

Comment: If I knew how to "fake" the service in a Plunker I could, but I don't know how.  The only thing that comes back from the service is a string returned by the database.  It either has a number like" 3 Deficiencies Found" or "No Deficiencies Found".

Comment: @RaniRadcliff you don't need to 'fake'. Just take some dummy URL that returns JSON response, in my example I took from Google maps location

Answer (score 0):

> Regards to `<span ng-model="definfo">{{definfo}}</span>`

You don't need `ng-model` directive here. Enough to use `{{definfo}}` or better way like folks pointed to use `ng-bind` like:

```
<span ng-bind="definfo"></span>
```

> I tried using `$apply()` which gives me an error

Generally, developers use `$scope.$apply` when get callback from 3d party code like jQuery that stay out of digest cycle. So don't use it. BTW, safety way is to use `$timeout` for example a.e. wrap as:

```
 $timeout(function () {
   $scope.definfo = data;
 });
```

I believe if you don't use Promise chain you can use `success` and `error` callbacks (what you actually did) instead to use `then()`

---

> About `$http.get('/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/GetDeficiencyInfo');`

`$http.get` returns original Promise but it also returns `status 'Ok'`, config, headers ... and i'm sure you don't want parse full response in your controller.
So I would create new Promise in your service and fetch results only.

So instead: `return $http.get(URL);` I would write in Service:

```
  this.getDeficiencyInfo = function () {          
  var deferred = $q.defer(); 
      $http({method: 'GET', url: URL}).then(function(res){
         deferred.resolve(res.data); 
      }, function (error) {
            console.error(error);
            deferred.resolve({error:error}); //actually you can reject
        });    
     return deferred.promise;
  };
```

<kbd>[DEMO in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3co0bj6/)</kbd>

Comment: I probably should have stated that I already tried using timeout as well with no difference.  I'll add that to my description.  Thanks.

Comment: my original Html was <span ng-bind="definfo"></span>.  I thought adding the model might help.

Comment: I hate that people can down vote your answer anonymously.  It is equivalent to throwing stones and hiding your hands.  SO should make a rule that if you down vote a question or answer you have to supply the submitter with an explanation.  On another note, do you know why the scope variable would change after being set by the original variable?  I am assuming that there must be some logically reason.  Thanks for all of your help by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, although I don't know "why" it caused this particular issue.  When the page first loads `$scope.definfo` is set by a variable from another http call.  The variable `var pagedata = []` holds a lot of information that comes back from the service when the page is first rendered.  The scope variable is then set with this code: `$scope.definfo = pagedata.DeficiencyInfo`.  Removing that line and calling the function `getDefInfo` directly, sets and updates the scope variable as desired.  Perhaps one of you gurus could explain why that is to me and others so that it may help others.  Thank you to everyone for your help.