# Angular Js: What is The Difference between this two statements from angular js?

Tags: angularjs

Already I read many things about ng-model and ng-bind but still i m not satisfied with this

Code statement 1:

```
ng-model="table.process_data.username"
```

Code statement 2:

```
ng-bind="table.process_data.username"
```

i think both statements works are same?
if i m wrong then plese help me to understand this thing

Comment: if i'm not wrong ng-model works on inputs so the value can be modified while ng-bind is used only to display a value

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/12420157/5621827

Comment: okay but i cant find that question so i asked @jitender

Comment: Thanks for the comment and suggestion  All

Answer (score 0):

ng-bind is same as string interpolation not the same as ng-model.
ng-model is used for 2 way databinding and ng-bind is only for one way databinding.

if you have written a variable in ng-model , any change in html will always be available in controller as well and vice versa , however this is not the case with ng-bind.

Consider ng-bind as string interpolation {{}} , its functionality is same as string interpolation.